# How to remove <head></head> element in Webpack 2 style-loader?

Tags: javascript, html, css, webpack-2, webpack-style-loader

Here's the generated HTML by webpack, and I wanted to remove the **head** element

```
<head><link href="css/common.min.css" rel="stylesheet"></head>
```

And I found this link for targeting the output css file and to be inserted somewhere else
https://webpack.js.org/loaders/style-loader/#insertinto

I tried this but it's not working, please help.

require('../styles/main.css?insertInto=#host::shadow>#root');